# Multi-factor auth with Kerberos and RADIUS

Tags: authentication, kerberos, radius

I am looking for a solution in order to allow a multi-factor authentication for a Kerberos-based logon service.
By reading some articles, I found some good references about RADIUS, that provides a set of features in order to achieve this goal.

Considering that I am working on a Windows-based environment, is it possible to integrate the current Kerberos environment with RADIUS?
Are there some other general advises to take into account?

Answer (score 0):

You can check LoginTC two factor authentication to see if this resolves your use case. The LoginTC RADIUS Connector can be installed in a Microsoft Hyper-V server and be used for both first factor and second factor authentication.To install and configure the LoginTC RADIUS Connector follow these guidelines:

https://www.logintc.com/docs/connectors/radius.html

Your current Kerberos environment could be integrated with the LoginTC RADIUS Connector following these steps:

https://www.eduroam.us/node/90